# Work out the link count of inode number?

Tags: linux, inode

How can I work out the link count of an inode number? If I know the inode number is, say, 592255 - what workings out can I do to find out the link count?

I know directories have a link count of at least 2, but don't know how to work it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Finding the link count using the name

You can use the `stat` command to get a link count on a given file/directory:

```
$ stat lib/
  File: ‘lib/’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 11666186    Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    saml)   Gid: ( 1000/    saml)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2014-03-21 18:16:10.521963381 -0400
Modify: 2014-01-13 17:16:49.438408973 -0500
Change: 2014-01-14 17:57:46.636255446 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Taking a look at the man page for `stat`:

```
%h     number of hard links
%i     inode number
```

So you can get just this value directly using `stat`'s `--printf` or `--format` output capabilities:

```
$ stat --printf="%h\n" lib/
3

$ stat --format="%h" lib/
3

$ stat -c "%h" lib/
3
```

#### Finding the link count using the inode

If on the other hand you know the inode number only you can work backwards like so:

```
$ ls -id lib
11666186 lib

$ find -inum 11666186 -exec stat -c "%h" {} +
3
```

#### References

- [Hard links and Unix file system nodes (inodes)](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/04f/notes/links_and_inodes.html)

Comment: You've made the same mistake as me, the question is to find the link count from the inode number...

Comment: @Graeme - fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Give the inode number to the `find` command and tell it to run the `stat` command on the file:

```
find . -inum #### -exec stat -c "%h" {} \;
```

Comment: For a good concise explanation of inodes and directories see: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/04f/notes/links_and_inodes.html

Comment: Also of note: OSX uses a different version of stat, and so instead of `-c`, it requires the `-f` flag used as follows: `find . -inum #### -exec stat -f "%l" {} \;` (`%l` being "Number of hard links to file.")

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
ls -l passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1402 2008-03-30 17:49 passwd
```

This number (1) is actually the link-count of the file, when referring to a file, or the number of contained directory entries, when referring to a directory (including the . and .. entries).

Also for example

```
ls -i /etc/passwd
8654127 /etc/passwd
```

This is inode number for /etc/passwd. Now you can find how many links is actualy linked with this number of inode 8654127 with:

```
find /etc/ -inum 8654127
/etc/passwd
```

In my example it is only /etc/passwd, so you can do for your case:

```
find / -inum 592255
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the link count from the inode *without* searching the full filesystem, on an `ext2`/`ext3`/`ext4` filesystem you can use `debugfs`. The down side here is that you require to know the device and have root privileges. The upside of course is that it can be much, much faster. For a file with inode `5638454` on `dev/sda2`:

```
sudo debugfs -R 'stat <5638454>' /dev/sda2
```

On `btrfs`, given mount point `/mnt` instead of the device:

```
stat -c %h $(sudo btrfs inspect-internal inode-resolve 5638454 /mnt)
```